# Select rows where column in different rows must have exactly the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select `userid` where have certifications **BA+B** (it can be **BA+B+C**, is parametric from application) **BA** and also **B** both values.

Sample table data:

```
id, userid, certification
1    1         A
2    1         BA
3    1         C
4    2         B
5    2         C
6    2         BA
```

Only the `userid=2` which has the certifications **BA** and also **B**. Expected result:

```
userid
 2
```

Comment: It may be more than one e.g BA+B, BA+C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` with `COUNT DISTINCT` to make sure both BA and B are there.

```
select userid 
from MyTable
where certification IN ('B', 'BA')
group by userid
having count(distinct certification ) = 2
```

Comment: The problem is that may be not only BA+B but many combinations like BA+B+C and BA+B

Comment: Only BA and B will pass the WHERE clause, which is performed before GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: Sorry if I can not write it correctly. The filter is dependent of parameter of application. It may be filter all user where have certification BA Or BA+B Or B. The query is building dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, userid int, certification varchar(5));
insert into @tbl values
(1, 1, 'A' ),
(2, 1, 'BA'),
(3, 1, 'C' ),
(4, 2, 'B' ),
(5, 2, 'C' ),
(6, 2, 'BA');   

select userid 
from @tbl
group by userid
having sum(case when certification = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when certification = 'BA' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

It forces for each `userid` to have at least one `B` and one `BA` certifiaction.